# Starting an Android service with parameters

Tags: android

I want to start a service that has parameters

```
public BackgroundHelperService(String name)
```

How can I do this using

```
Intent service = new Intent(cnx, BackgroundHelperService.class);
```

I cannot pass the name param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot pass the name param.

Correct. You cannot pass constructor parameters. If `BackgroundHelperService` is extending `IntentService`, please supply a name yourself:

```
public BackgroundHelperService() {
  super("BackgroundHelperService");
}
```

Comment: That worked, I noticed that if I do something like  Toast.makeText(this, "Background Helper Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); it will throw an exception because of the 'this' word.  Do you know why this is?  It seems that there is no Context for some reason.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @jax: I would not be surprised if you cannot create `Toasts` from services.

Comment: @commonsWare but I have used Toasts in my other normal Services, ie not IntentSerivces

Comment: I cant even get hold of the notification service.    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Comment: it seems if you do this in the onHandleIntent(Intent intent) it works, you just can't do it inside the constructor

Comment: @jax: Never implement a constructor on an `Activity` or `Service`.